# spring LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean does not work with persistentunitmanager

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-orm

I want to use LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean with multiple persistence units.

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="jpaEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="jpaPersistenceUnitManager"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaPersistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="pu-user”/>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence-user.xml</value>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence-customer.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSources">
        <map>
            <entry key=“userDataSource" value-ref=“userDataSource"/>
            <entry key="customerDataSource" value-ref=“customerDataSource"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref=“userDataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" primary="true">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="jpaEntityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="simple.user.persistence"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="simple.customer.persistence"/>
```

persistence xmls are defined as follows:

```
<persistence-unit name="pu-user" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <jta-data-source>userDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <non-jta-data-source>userDataSource</non-jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
```

DataSources are defined as follows:

```
<bean id="userDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
    <property name="maxTotal" value="32"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="32"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1"/>
</bean>
```

UserRepository and CustomerRepository are defined as follows:

```
package simple.user.persistence;

@Repository
public class UserRepository {
   @PersistenceContext(unitName="pu-user”)
   EntityManager em;

   @Transactional
   User createUser(User user) {
       em.persist(user);
   }
}
```

When I run my unit test, I am getting the following exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'pu-customer' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:139)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findNamedEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:556)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:538)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:707)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:680)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
... 60 more
```

Looked at the source code for EntityManagerFactoryUtils. The findEntityManagerFactory method at line 132 clearly compares only the defaultPersistentUnitName and ignores other persistent unit names defined in DeafultPersistentUnitManager. This looks to me like a bug. Please let me know what do you think.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java

Answer (score 0):

When I've needed multiple persistence units I create multiple LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and then each LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean would have a corresponding JpaTransactionManager.

The one ripple is that if you have multiple transaction managers you would need to name the transaction manager you want to use in the @Transactional annotation.

I suppose if you need to be accessing both persistence units within a single transaction you would need a JTA transaction manager to marry the 2 JPA transaction managers -- not sure what your requirements are for that though.

Comment: Thanks John. Appreciate your reply. I am currently using this approach. Our production db has 10 SQL schemas. I am declaring a separate LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and JpaTransactionManager for each one of them. It adds a slight overhead in code maintenance. If my original config works, then I can reduce the amount of configuration needed.

Comment: Having multiple is the only way I've found to get this working.  If the issue is multiple schemas on a single DB then an alternative solution could be granting access to the required tables to a single schema (perhaps an 11th app schema).

Comment: Thanks John. We are using a versioning framework. It creates separate global history tables for each schema. That is why, we need to create separate EntityManagers to access them.